# Adding javascript tags to vaadin UI head

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, vaadin

When you create a vaadin 7 project in eclipse, execution begins in the UI class.

I was wondering if there was some way to add a javascript tag such as this to the header of the html page generated when executing a vaadin project.

```
<script src="amcharts.js"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing%20the%20startup%20page%20in%20an%20application) is a page that describe how to do this.
You can write your own code into the modifyBootstrapPage method:

```
@Override
public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse response) {
    response.getDocument().head().append("<script src=\"amcharts.js\"/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write own component which use JavaScript. Look into [that chapter](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.javascript.html) in the official Vaadin book.